# First python program error message

Tags: python

I tried to write my first python program and I already get an error message. In the textbook introduction to computer science using python i found the following code:

```
name = input('What is your name? ')
print('Hello', name)
print('Welcome to Python!')
```

I checked multiple times for errors and I'm quite sure i typed it exactly like the textbook states. I saved the program as MyFirstProgram.py and after that i ran the module (by pressing F5). If i understand correctly the program asks you to fill in a name. So i typed 'John'. But when i did, the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Wout/.ipython/MyFirstProgram.py", line 3, in <module>
    name = input('What is your name? ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'John' is not defined
```

Why is 'John' not defined? Isn't it the purpose of the program to enter any name? Why do i have to define it? I followed the instructions to the letter...

Kind regards

Comment: And since you are using python 2.x, you probably don't want the parentheses in the `print` statement.

Answer (score 2):

`input`, in Python 2, evaluates the input as if it were a snippet of Python code. This is almost never what you want. Use `raw_input` instead.

By the way, you're writing your code as if it were Python 3, but you appear to be using a Python 2 interpreter. If you run your code with Python 3, it will work fine (`input` in Python 3 is the same as `raw_input` in Python 2).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of an `input()`, since you are on python-2.x:

```
name = raw_input('What is your name? ')
print('Hello', name)
print('Welcome to Python!')
```

prints:

```
What is your name? John
('Hello', 'John')
Welcome to Python!
```

Comment: Add `from __future__ import print_function` if you want `print` to behave as a function and output `Hello John` instead of `('Hello', 'John')`

Answer (score 0):

You are following a textbook for Python 3 but using Python 2. In Python 2, must use `raw_input` and don't need brackets on print statements.

Answer (score 0):

`'John'` will work with `input` (`John` won't work), however you should use `raw_input()` like the others said